# Validate in merge function pandas

Tags: python, pandas, validation, merge

Today I was trying to go a little deeper in the `merge()` function of pandas, and I found the option `validate`, which, as reported in the documentation, can be:

> validate : string, default None
>
> If specified, checks if merge is of specified type.
>
> “one_to_one” or “1:1”: check if merge keys are unique in both left and
> right datasets. “one_to_many” or “1:m”: check if merge keys are unique
> in left dataset. “many_to_one” or “m:1”: check if merge keys are
> unique in right dataset.   "many_to_many” or “m:m”: allowed, but does
> not result in checks.

I have looked around to find a working example on where and how to use this function, but I couldn't find any. Moreover when I tried to apply it to a group of `DataFrame`'s I was merging, it didn't seem to change the output.
Can anyone give me a working example, to make me understand it better?

Thanks in advance,

Mattia

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The new `valdate` param will raise a `MergeError` if the validation fails, example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('aabc'),'b':np.random.randn(4)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('aabc'),'b':np.random.randn(4)})

print(df1)
print(df2)

   a         b
0  a -2.557152
1  a -0.145969
2  b -1.629560
3  c -0.233517

   a         b
0  a -0.352038
1  a  0.490438
2  b  0.319452
3  c -0.599481
```

Now if we merge on column `'a'` without `validate`:

```
In[39]:
df1.merge(df2, on='a')

Out[39]: 
   a       b_x       b_y
0  a -2.557152 -0.352038
1  a -2.557152  0.490438
2  a -0.145969 -0.352038
3  a -0.145969  0.490438
4  b -1.629560  0.319452
5  c -0.233517 -0.599481
```

This works but we get more rows for 'a' as column 'b' is different, now we pass `validate='1:1'`, we get an error:

```
MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in either
left or right dataset; not a one-to-one merge
```

if we pass `validate='1:m'` we get a different error:

```
MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in left
dataset;not a one-to-many merge
```

Again this fails the validation, if we pass `'m:m'`:

```
In[42]:
df1.merge(df2, on='a',validate='m:m')

Out[42]: 
   a       b_x       b_y
0  a -2.557152 -0.352038
1  a -2.557152  0.490438
2  a -0.145969 -0.352038
3  a -0.145969  0.490438
4  b -1.629560  0.319452
5  c -0.233517 -0.599481
```

no error occurs and we get the same merged df if we had not passed the `validate` param

The api docs don't give an example but the [what's new](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-validation) section does, the original [github enhancement](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16270) also gives further background information

Comment: The docs and full code is accessible at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas, you can make push requests, these will be reviewed prior to merging, or you could submit an issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues to request an enhancement to the docs but the devs are busy and as this is a low-effort task they will tell you that you are welcome to submit a push request